# My female red eared slider's awkward behavior is concerning me

Tags: behavior, reptiles, turtles

My female red eared slider' has recently been displaying an awkward and concerning behavior. She has been:

- swimming frantically;
- being mean (biting anything);
- hasn't been basking for 4 days;
- trying to climb tank walls;
- tearing apart plastic plant.

What could be the reason for this behavior? She has never done this before!

Is she mad?

Is she bored/lonely? Her fish friend recently died.

Could it be from our air conditioner breaking 2 days ago?

Please help me.

Comment: Except for the tearing a plastic plant apart, swimming frantically is a symptom of great distress, as if the water quality and chemical levels are having issues. Always worth a check!

Comment: related: [RES laying eggs into the water](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18912/red-eared-slider-laying-eggs-into-the-water/25383#25383)

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your Red Ear Slider might be carrying eggs. One of the signs is going from calm to hyper, nonstop like you described. IF you can take her outside and let her roam around she might nest.

You can try feeling for eggs. If you can feel eggs then you know for sure whats going on.

Female turtles can have the need to lay eggs without ever seen a male turtle!

Click [here](https://youtu.be/qY2pRyQgn9o) to see a video of how to feel for eggs.